# Posting A Form To An External URL From A Google Site

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, google-sites

I've created an external HTML form to be hosted on a site outside of a main site that is coded in Rails. I've tested this using http://htmledit.squarefree.com/ (jsfiddle didn't post to the server) and it works.

However, the client wants to put the form on a Google Sites page. I've added it as a HTML box, but when I submit the form the server doesn't see a peep.

The form code is:

```
<form action="http://thesite.com/signup_ext" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="first_name" />
  <input type="text" name="last_name" />
  <input type="text" name="email" />
  <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Sign Up" />
</form>
```

Is this possible to do on Google Sites?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to create a Google Apps Script file, and make it a Stand Alone Web App.  A Stand Alone Web App is basically a website that you can't map a domain name to.   Put the form into the Web App, then put the Apps Script into an Apps Script Gadget in the Google Site.

[Guide to HTML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/)

You will need to use the client side API to send form data to the Apps Script `.gs` function.

[Google Documentation - google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

Comment: Thanks Sandy. Could this also be done using JavaScript?

Comment: I haven't had much luck with the HTML box.  In fact, the example in the documentation for using jQuery seems to be broken.  But if you want to keep trying the HTML box, I would get rid of the `method="post"` attribute in the Form tag, change the submit button to a regular button; get the values out of the form inputs individually, and then try adding them to search string parameters of the URL to your site.  Then your site would need to process the url search string values.  You could also try making an ajax POST request.

Comment: The HTML Service uses JavaScript.  So you can use JavaScript in a SCRIPT tag with HTML Service.